# How can I tell if a process is currently forking at runtime?

Tags: linux, fork

Something like "int is_forking();" would be nice =)

I have a problem that malloc is deadlocking when called from within a fork call.

Comment: Eh? Fork is a syscall. `kmalloc()` might be called from within it, but not `malloc()`.

Comment: This sounds like a total [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Haha, but *I KNOW* what the solution is =)


Ok here is what I am doing. I am hooking some functions and logging them, my logging goes kaput (malloc deadlock) if the process is in the middle of a fork.

Comment: Use `strace` or `ltrace` and also `gdb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX definition specifies:

> From the application's perspective, a fork() call should appear atomic.

Thus, in theory nothing else (malloc or otherwise) can happen in parallel.

In practice, using `pthread_atfork()` to provide your own callbacks to maintain an `is_forking` flag; you can set this flag when the `prepare` callback is invoked, and clear it when the `parent` or `child` callbacks are invoked.

Comment: In bionic some stuff happens in the libc part like calling cpuacct_add (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/40eabe2/libc/bionic/fork.c)

Comment: @djp Ahh. This is probably a place where the platform should be specified.

Comment: @djp, I've modified my answer appropriately.